# Adding slick carousel to Magento 2 homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento2, slick.js

I'm having an issue with what I think should be a basic thing but I'm obviously doing something wrong, all I want to do is have a basic banner slider using slick slider jquery plugin. I have a custom theme working fine and I've downloaded the slick.min.js to **app/design/frontend/Pyxis/pyxistheme/web/js/slick.min.js**

I have then created the requirejs-config.js in my **/web** folder and added this:

```
`var config = {
    paths: {
        slick:        'js/slick.min'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};`
```

which when I view the page source and view the file I can see that code.

My issue is that when I add the jquery code to a CMS page ie homepage like so:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'slick.min'
    ], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".home-banners").slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                arrows: true,
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I get a console error saying slick.min.js cannot be found? I have ran these commands in my terminal:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
**php -d memory_limit=2048M bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f**
**php -d memory_limit=2048M bin/magento cache:flush**

Any idea why it can't find my slick.min.js file?

Thankyou

Comment: did you try the setup:di:compile? not sure if it works but maybe:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path for `requirejs-config.js` is wrong, you should have it in `app/design/frontend/Pyxis/pyxistheme/` not inside `/web`.

Next thing, in `requirejs-config.js` you map `slick: 'js/slick.min'` but in phtml you are using `slick.min`. Try change to `slick`.

After this, just use this commands:

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* 
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f
bin/magento cache:flush
```